How can i stop horizontal movement of text upon value changing in flutter
I am using the Align() widget with Alignment(x, y) for a text widget, the problem that I have is that when I change the value of the text, it moves a little bit to the left, instead, I want it to extend from the end, I have tried to change the textAlign to textAlign.start and textAlign.left but still nothing, how can I achieve this? you guys can check what I'm trying to say here: https://streamable.com/pxn3h7

Alignment(0,0) is Alignment.center!  And  it looks like your text widget is staying nicely centered. with your text flush-left inside that wiget.  If you turn on widget boundaries using devtools, it'll be clearer what is happening.  So what behavior do you actually want?
